# Dynamically change status bar color in iOS for PWA apps

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

Can we dynamically change the status bar (the one at the top) color in iOS for PWA apps?
I am using Angular and I have been trying to modify the ***apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style*** meta tag during runtime but it seems like it doesn't work.

```
this.meta.removeTag("name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style'");

if (isDarkMode) {
  this.bodyElement.style.setProperty('--mainPageBackground', '#000');
  this.bodyElement.style.setProperty('--mainTextColor', '#FFF');
  this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content: `black-translucent` }, `name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style'`);
}
else {
  this.bodyElement.style.setProperty('--mainPageBackground', '#FFF');
  this.bodyElement.style.setProperty('--mainTextColor', '#000');
  this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content: `default` }, `name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style'`);
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I haven't tried this yet as still early stages of dev but I am trying to foresee any issues with the curent design of our app...

Answer (score 0):

Use `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">` and apply desired color to body and white or whatever background color to page wrapper. I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You could try [this solution](https://gordonlesti.com/change-theme-color-via-javascript/) for Android/Chrome, but adapted for iOS below:

```
var appleThemeColor = document.querySelector("meta[name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style]");
if(isDarkMode) appleThemeColor.setAttribute("content", "#000");
else appleThemeColor.setAttribute("content", "#FFF");
```

Cheers!